# placing an element to the right in a linear layout in android

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout

I want to place an image to the right of the view. For that I am tyring to use something like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

...some other elements

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/image_icon" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

...
</RelativeLayout>
```

The above seems to put the image somewhere in the center. How do I ensure that the image is right aligned regardless of whether we are in portrait or landscape mode?

Thanx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following seems to work. Two changes 
1. use orientation = vertical as suggested by Zortkun
2. Use wrap_content in layout_width.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingsIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/settings_icon" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:orientation="vertical" ` was missing all along.. :) remove it and u ll see..

Answer (score 0):

The default orientation of `LinearLayout` is horizontal. Make sure the Linear layout's orientation is set to **Vertical** ortherwise you cannot aling stuff horizontally.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
```

Comment: Thanx for a super quick response - but sorry - that did not work.

Comment: whatelse is in your `linearlayout` ?

Comment: Nothing else. The remaining stuff is within the outer relative layout - basically I want a row with only one image at the right hand side. I can of course use left margin (that works) but I want to use alignment so I do not have to worry about portrait/landscape mode...

Comment: yeah you shouldnT use margins in that situation. It should be easy tho. Could you please post your entire xml so we can test better?

Comment: Yeah it s definitely the layout orientation: `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Hi Zortkun - thanx for your answer. I did not need to have the "center}right". I thought I had tried this before. Perhaps the "orientation = vertical" is the new thing. Thank you !

Comment: Hi ZortKun, Can you please edit your answer to use the layout I gave in my answer (since I know that works in my particular scenario). I would like to mark your answer as the right one. Thanx!

Comment: damn you are right! i lost the fight :D i missed that one.. sorry. well, you can always mark urs as the answer. doNT worry :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Linearlayout if you use only one view inside the Linearlayout.

Anyway its here,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

//...some other elements

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/image_icon" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```